# What is the right way to modify Angular Material core function?

Tags: angular

I have to modify some codes in '@angular/cdk/esm2015/drag-drop.js' but I do not know is there any way to modify it without directly changing the original file (ex: Override?).

```
//Original code
_getSiblingContainerFromPosition(item, x, y) {
return this._siblings.find((/**
          * @param {?} sibling
          * @return {?}
          */
         sibling => sibling._canReceive(item, x, y)));
}

//Modified code
_getSiblingContainerFromPosition(item, x, y) {
  //NEW CODE
}
```

Comment: Do not add code to a third party library. In Angular, we commonly use `npm`, your changes in the third party library will not reflect on other systems which take a pull of our application since they will have a fresh install of material. You will have to save the entire file to your app which is not a good practice. Not to mention, it will make life difficult if you ever try to upgrade. Instead try and explain your issue, there must be another way to solve it rather than directly modifying the third party library, if not and if it is a bug, you can open up an issue on material's Github.

Comment: @nash11 You're right. It is not a good practice to change the third party code. Yet, I have to modify it because the behaviour is not correct or not matching what I needed. 
So, I need the way to modify the function without directly changing on the third-party library but only override it. Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: Then please explain exactly what it is that you are trying to do in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I just want to know whether there is a way to override it. As you can see in my question, I just want to add some logic in the function - _getSiblingContainerFromPosition before it return me the result. Many thanks!